# Ошибки в конструкторе

Tags: c#, ооп

Я новичок в C#, прохожу книгу Троелсена. Есть класс Employee

```
partial class Employee
    {
        protected string empName;
        protected int empID;
        protected float currPay;
        protected int empAge;
        protected string empSSN;

        public Employee() { }
        public Employee(string name, int id, float pay)
            : this(name, 0, id, pay, "") { }

        /* public Employee(string name, int age, int id, float pay, string ssn)
            : this(name, age, id, pay)
        {
            empSSN = ssn;
        } */
        public Employee(string name, int age, int id, float pay, string ssn)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
            ID = id;
            Pay = pay;
            SSN = ssn;
        }

        //Методи

        public void GiveBonus(float amount)
        {
            Pay += amount;
        }
        public void DisplayStats()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"ID: {ID}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Age: {Age}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Pay: {Pay}");
        }

        //Свойства
        public string SSN
        {
            get => empSSN;
            set => empSSN = value;
        }
        public int Age
        {
            get => empAge;
            set => empAge = value;
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return empName; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length > 15)
                    Console.WriteLine("Error! Name length exceeds 15 characters!");
                else
                    empName = value;
            }
        }
        public int ID
        {
            get => empID;
            set => empID = value;
        }
        public float Pay
        {
            get => currPay;
            set => currPay = value;
        }
    }
```

И нужно добавить вот такой конструктор:

```
public Employee(string name, int age, int id, float pay, string ssn)
:this(name, age, id, pay)
{
empSSN = ssn;
}
```

чтобы в дальнейшем передать его классу, который наследуется от Employee через base. Но пишет ошибки, что не существует конструктора на 4 элемента. В книге больше ничего не написано, ни про какой другой конструктор на 4 элемента ни слова. Как записать конструктор или по другому решить ошибки?

Comment: Видимо автор пропустил этот момент, по другому нельзя решить ошибку кроме как создать конструктор с 4-мя параметрами.

Comment: Хорошо, уже сделал. Работает, спасибо